# How to implement a multi-hierachcy microsoft reporter

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, report

One of my reports is required to display data in a  multi-hierachcy way.

The data structure is like Org>Prog>Event.

Let's say I have the raw data source like:

```
OrgId|ProgId|EventId|PlanValue
1    |A     |Z      |10
1    |A     |Y      |20
2    |A     |Z      |5
3    |A     |F      |2
3    |B     |Z      |3
```

Reprot Layout:
Using the 1st col to put all different ids, but with different colors to distinguish the id type.

So 
blue is Orgid; 
red is Progid; 
green is EventId

In that report, i need to see the total plan value of a Organisation, total plan value of one of this organisation's programmes and total plan values of one of organisation's events.

```
OrgId/ProgId/EventId|PlanValue
1(blue)             |30
A(red)              |30
Z(green)            |10
Y(green)            |20
________________________
2(blue)             |5
A(red)              |5
Z(green)            |5
________________________
3(blue)             |5
A(red)              |2
F(green)            |2
B(red)              |3
Z(green)            |3
```

Any tutorials or thoughts will be helpful.

Comment: Not getting the question what you want to say? How did you structured this output?

Comment: @dev i clarified the question a bit. I am trying to implement a  multi-hierachcy report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don t need to think it complicated the tricky part of this is the get getting data as you wanted and to that you can use similar sql as below, [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6feee/8)

```
select ORGID,'','', SUM(PLANVALUE) as total from table1
group by ORGID
union all
select ORGID,ProgId,'',  SUM(PLANVALUE) as total from table1
group by ORGID,ProgId
union all
select ORGID,ProgId,EventId,  SUM(PLANVALUE) as total from table1
group by ORGID,ProgId,EventId
```

if you already have raw data as a result like dataTable all Entity list you can achieve same result with LinQ. After you get the result you wanted just sort it as you want and bind a repeater for colouring and separator  you can use  conditional statment like ProgId != "" ? "color:blue" : "color:red".